# How I can concatenate some bytes read from a stream before hashing them in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to read a binary file concatenate some bytes ans hash it:

```
import hashlib
from io import BytesIO
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    in_file = sys.argv[1]
    file_data = open(in_file, 'rb').read()
    stream = BytesIO(file_data)

    digest = hashlib.new('sha256')
    # Concat 32 bytes to inpuit data and then hash it
    digest.update(('\x00' * 32) + stream.read())
```

What I want is to concatenate 32 bytes initialized with zero to the bytes read through the stream, then hash it alltogether.

But seems the oneliner:

```
('\x00' * 32) + stream.read()
```

Not to cut the chase due to the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

DO you know an alternate approach in my case?

Comment: so you want the same concatenation, but in another functional byte-way? By the way, didn't you get an error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str` ?

Comment: Yes I got it that why I am looking for a way to concatenate bytes.

Comment: `'\x00'` is a `str` not a `byes` object. The error is pretty clear

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) function to create a zero-filled byte sequence of a specified length:

```
In [1018]: bytes(32)
Out[1018]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

---

In your case:
`digest.update(bytes(32) + stream.read())`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to concatenate in order to get the digested value. You should better call the update method several times to avoid creating a potentially costly copy of the file content. If the file is very large, you should also load it in chunks.

```
digest.update(32 * b'\x00')
chunk_size = 1024**2
while True:
    chunk = stream.read(chunk_size)
    if not chunk:
        break
    digest.update(chunk)
```